# Different result for two identical arguments

Tags: excel

I used two IF functions to find the maximum value of a range, but return 0 if I slightly change the function by using AND function. Please help.

This works and returns an integer:

`{=MAX(IF(MONTH(A58:A67)=MONTH(K50),IF(YEAR(A58:A67)=YEAR(K50),B58:B67)))}`

this one always returns 0:

```
{=MAX(IF(AND(MONTH(A58:A67)=MONTH(K50),YEAR(A58:A67)=YEAR(K50)),B58:B67))}
```

Comment: Have you considered maxifs() ?

Comment: At the risk of being pendantic, `0` *is* an integer. That said, what you have is not a slight change, the entire logic of the two functions is very different. If `AND(MONTH(A58:A67)=MONTH(K50),YEAR(A58:A67)=YEAR(K50)` returns false, then, if the cell is formatted as number, the function will return the numeric value of false, which is `0`

Comment: @solar mike Yes I do, but seems i cannot get month() function into the formula:

'=MAXIFS(B58:B67, A58:A67, MONTH(K50))'  -----> Syntax Error
'=MAXIFS(B58:B67, month(A58:A67), MONTH(K50))' -----> Syntax Error
'=MAXIFS(B58:B67, A58:A67, month(A58:A67) = MONTH(K50))' -----> Syntax Error
'=MAXIFS(B58:B67, month(A58:A67), month(A58:A67) = MONTH(K50))' -----> Syntax Error

Answer (score 1):

Mostly one cannot using `AND` in array context properly.

In your example the

`IF(MONTH(A58:A67)=MONTH(K50),IF(YEAR(A58:A67)=YEAR(K50),B58:B67))`

evaluates to

`IF({TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;...;FALSE}, IF({FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;...;TRUE}, {B58:B67}))`

dependent on whether `MONTH(A58:A67)=MONTH(K50)` is `TRUE` or `FALSE` and `YEAR(A58:A67)=YEAR(K50)` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

That means if the first is `TRUE` then check the second and if the second also is `TRUE`, then take the corresponding value from array `{B58:B67}` into the `MAX`, else take `FALSE`, which counts `0`, into the `MAX`.

But

`IF(AND(MONTH(A58:A67)=MONTH(K50),YEAR(A58:A67)=YEAR(K50)),B58:B67)`

evaluates to

`IF(AND({TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;...;FALSE},{FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;...;TRUE}),{B58:B67})`

So both the `{TRUE;FALSE;...}` arrays are in the `AND` and that will only be `TRUE` if there is not a single `FALSE` in both the arrays, else `FALSE` which counts `0` in the `MAX`.

And even if there would not be a single `FALSE` in both the arrays, then always the whole array `B58:B67` would be the result in the `MAX`.

Comment: This for your help, that cleared my confusion.

But to move on, I still cannot get it work even if i adapt maxifs function, please help...

=MAXIFS(B58:B67, A58:A67, MONTH(K50))  -----> Syntax Error
=MAXIFS(B58:B67, month(A58:A67), MONTH(K50)) -----> Syntax Error
=MAXIFS(B58:B67, A58:A67, month(A58:A67) = MONTH(K50)) -----> Syntax Error
=MAXIFS(B58:B67, month(A58:A67), month(A58:A67) = MONTH(K50)) -----> Syntax Error

Comment: @user10883948: What is the goal? Avoiding the array formulas? Because your first approach with nested `IF`s works though. `MAXIFS` cannot work this way since it needs `criteria_range`s as ranges and not as formulas. So you would need two helper columns in which the MONTH and the YEAR are calculated from the dates in `A58:A67`. Then `=MAXIFS(B58:B67, [helperRangeWithMonthsOfA58:A67], MONTH(K50), [helperRangeWithYearsOfA58:A67], YEAR(K50))`.